# Git: How to merge your changes to your branch, when you need to upgrade your branch with other's changes?

Tags: git

I am new to git and am really struggling to understand many of it concepts.

I had to change 1 file on a branch I hadnt touched for a few days, so checked out that branch, made the changes and pushed it back. However, I got an error saying something like I was trying to `fast-forward` and had content I needed to merge. So, I decided to `git checkout master` to get my branch inline with the one on master.

I then ran `git status` and see that I have thousands of new and modified files ready to be pushed - not just the one I worked on.

I don't want to push all these files into my branch. Is there a way I can get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem very confused about how Git works and what that non fast forward error actually means.  All the error means is that some other developer has made one or more commits to the branch on the remote since you last pulled.  As a result, Git is refusing to blindly apply your commits to that branch since you last pulled because in general conflicts would arise which would require manual editing of files to resolve.  All you need to do is to pull that branch locally, resolve any conflicts should they occur, and then push your branch out.  Something like this should work:

```
git pull origin yourBranch
# resolve merge conflicts, shouls they occur
git push origin yourBranch
```

With regard to the `master` branch, you don't need to worry about it right now.  Perhaps at a later time, when the entire feature is ready to go into `master`, this will become a concern.

I have no idea why switching to `master` gave you thousands of changed files.  But the good news is this isn't your direct problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My only question is wouldn't my initial `git checkout` also grab the changes the other developer made?

Comment: `git checkout` switches branches, it doesn't modify any branch.  You need to merge or rebase.